# asp.net regular expression validator for email or numeric

Tags: asp.net, validation

Is it possible use a regular expression validator for a textbox which accepts either user email or phone number (11 digits number which begins with 09) ?
so one regex is needed which accepts one of two cases, email or number.

Answer (score 0):

For Email : "\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*.\w+([-.]\w+)*"

[0][9][0-9]

Comment: i want both in a same validator, if it is an email OR phone number.